# Strange fadeIn() and fadeOut() Problems jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a backwards-compatible version of something designed in CSS3. It mostly works, but with a few problems, that I hope you guys can figure out.

Look at this page first to understand what I'm talking about:

http://bearce.me/new-home/index.htm

It works prefectly in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari. I'm working on the IE tweaks, using jQuery.

So, as you can see, when you hover over one column, the other two columns fade to black and white. This is done using four different images, and fading the images out to reveal the correct one. The issue I'm having is how the images fade out. In IE, when you hover over each column, the images do fade out, but first the full color image flashes. Also, if you quickly drag your cursor over the entire set, it flashes like 4 times. I know how to use `.stop(true,false)`, and have tried that, as well as `.stop(true,true)`, `.stop(false,false)`, and `.stop(false,true)`, each of which presents its own problems, mainly only one image fading, while the others just suddenly jump.

My script:

```
$("#left").hover(
    function () {
        // fading
        $("#slider #main").fadeOut(500);
        $("#slider #web").fadeOut(500);
        $("#slider #graphics").fadeOut(500);
        // description animation
        $("#left .more").stop(true,false).delay(150).animate({height:"120px"}, 500);
    },
    function () {
        // fading
        $("#slider #main").fadeIn(500);
        $("#slider #web").fadeIn(500);
        $("#slider #graphics").fadeIn(500);
        // description animation
        $("#left .more").stop(true,false).delay(150).animate({height:"0px"}, 500);
    }
);

$("#center").hover(
    function () {
        // fading
        $("#slider #main").fadeOut(500);
        $("#slider #scripting").fadeOut(500);
        $("#slider #web").fadeOut(500);
        // description animation
        $("#center .more").stop(true,false).delay(150).animate({height:"120px"}, 500);
    },
    function () {
        // fading
        $("#slider #main").fadeIn(500);
        $("#slider #scripting").fadeIn(500);
        $("#slider #web").fadeIn(500);
        // description animation
        $("#center .more").stop(true,false).delay(150).animate({height:"0px"}, 500);
    }
);

$("#right").hover(
    function () {
        // fading
        $("#slider #main").fadeOut(500);
        $("#slider #scripting").fadeOut(500);
        $("#slider #graphics").fadeOut(500);
        // description animation
        $("#right .more").stop(true,false).delay(150).animate({height:"120px"}, 500);
    },
    function () {
        // fading
        $("#slider #main").fadeIn(500);
        $("#slider #scripting").fadeIn(500);
        $("#slider #graphics").fadeIn(500);
        // description animation
        $("#right .more").stop(true,false).delay(150).animate({height:"0px"}, 500);
    }
);
```

This version only fires if CSS Transitions are not supported, so that's why it works great in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari.

Also, is there a good way to shrink this down to one section, instead of three? I doubt it, but hey, I'm already asking questions, so might as well try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to code *everything* explicitly. This code should handle all your cases:

```
$('#home_nav > *').hoverIntent(function() {
  $('#slider img').eq($(this).index()).siblings().stop(true, false).fadeOut(500);
  $(this).find('.more').stop(true, false).animate({height: '120px'}, 500);
}, function() {
  $('#slider img').eq($(this).index()).siblings().stop(true, false).fadeIn(500);
  $(this).find('.more').stop(true, false).animate({height: '0px'}, 500);
});
```

This code seems redundant, so if anyone can suggest a way to condense it, I'd gladly fix my answer.

Comment: I like the idea, but unfortunately that doesn't work. The images aren't siblings, and this also fades out `.more`. Plus each hover fades out different images, so it doesn't quite work. EDIT: Woah, that works now. Don't understand how, but it does work. Still doesn't answer the original question, though.

Comment: I'll see what's up with the fading. It's probably events firing at the wrong times. Usually a `.stop()` before the animation code fixes this.

Comment: So this works nicely, but it's fading out the incorrect images for the side columns. http://bearce.me/new-home/index2.htm

Comment: Could you remove the modernizr code to look for CSS3 for a little bit? I'm running Chrome on Linux so I can't tell if my code fixes the animations or not

Comment: Done, http://bearce.me/new-home/index2.htm EDIT: Sorry, had to edit the CSS, too, now it should be done.

Comment: Swap the order of your images so that they are like so: `web, graphics, scripting`. The order of the images was backwards.

Comment: Nice, thanks, still flashing though if you mouse over the whole thing quickly.

Comment: You'll need the jQuery `hoverIntent` plugin for this. You code uses delays, but they don't account for the user just mousing over (the delays just delay firing, but don't actually stop firing if the user mouses out quickly). Download the plugin from [here] (http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) (if you can spare a few hundred bytes), include it like a regular ol' script, and use my updated code.